How do I skip the tutorial song in the Jubeat arcade game without an e-amusement card?
In the arcade version of Jubeat, whenever I insert credits to play the game, I am forced to play a minute-long tutorial song featuring a remixed version the can-can. (Video of the tutorial in a later version of Jubeat). A Reddit post and images shown during the game indicate the tutorial is skippable by purchasing and scanning an e-amusement card, but the arcade where I played Jubeat does not offer them.
How do I skip the tutorial song in the Jubeat arcade game without an e-amusement card?


Without an e-amusement pass compatible card, you can't.
I have searched through tutorials from every version of jubeat from YouTube except jubeat saucer (2012) and jubeat prop (2015), and found that:

In jubeat (2008, the first version), the tutorial could be terminated in the middle of it. (video)
In jubeat ripples (2009), the MODE SELECT screen allowed whether to show the tutorial or not. (video)
Between jubeat knit (2010) and jubeat saucer fulfill (2013), the tutorial could be selected just like any other songs in the SELECT MUSIC screen. (videos: jubeat knit, jubeat copious (2011), jubeat saucer fulfill)

I couldn't find one from jubeat saucer but it can be assumed that this version would be same as jubeat saucer fulfill, because jubeat saucer fulfill took the most of core concepts and systems from jubeat saucer.


Since jubeat Qubell (2016), you have no choice and the tutorial will automatically start after  the LOCAL MATCHING screen. (videos: jubeat Qubell, jubeat clan (2017), jubeat festo (2018), jubeat Ave. (2022), jubeat beyond the Ave. (2023))


You stated that your favorite arcade doesn't sell e-amusement pass cards, but if they sell Aime or BANAPASS cards with Amusement IC's three-peak logo on them, you can use one instead. It will work just like an e-amusement pass card.
A single Amusement IC card can be used for any compatible cabinets like BEMANI, maimai, CHUNITHM, Taiko, Initial D and Wangan Midnight, as long as they are connected to the network.
In jubeat, you will not see the tutorial from the second play using the card.

The machine seems to be outdated, because it is running jubeat Ave. (2022, reads "avenue", has cyanish color scheme), not the most recent version, jubeat beyond the Ave. (2023, has orange color scheme). jubeat Ave.'s server is still running so you can play the online features, but you should be aware that:

the two versions' servers are seperate,
you can transfer your user data to the newer version only once,
and after the transfer, any changes at the older version will not affect the data in the newer version.


Edit 2024-11-29:
In the process for citing videos, I found that jubeat saucer fulfill had actually the tutorial in SELECT MUSIC screen like previous versions.

I'd assumed it was the 2008 version of Jubear due to the copyright notice on the machine itself. Didn't realize it was running a newer version. Good catch.
